# Diff ignoring some specific characters

Tags: python, shell, unix, diff, cut

I have two huge text files (size from 1 to 5 GB) and I have to compute the difference between them using shell commands.
The problem is that, for each line of these files, I have to ignore some characters at specific positions.

At first time I used diff, cutting what I have to ignore from the two files:

diff <(cut -b1-58,69- FILE1.TXT) <(cut -b1-58,69- FILE2.TXT) > OUTPUT.TXT;

but the problem is that the output file does not contain cut characters.

Example

---

FILE1:

0123456311020130123456

aaaaaaA31102013aaaaaaA

bbbbbbb31102013bbbbbbb

---

FILE2:

0123456310920130123456

1111111310920131111111

aaaaaaB31092013aaaaaaB

bbbbbbb31092013bbbbbbb

---

the diff must ignore the characters from 8 to 15 of each line, returning in output also the new line:

---

OUTPUT:

1111111310920131111111

aaaaaaB31092013aaaaaaB

---

Can anybody help me?

Many thanks,
Francesco

Comment: Since you cut the characters away before `diff` can see them, it's obvious why they are missing in the output. If they were the same, then you wouldn't have to ignore them. Since they are different, which ones do you expect to see in the output?

Comment: I just added an example, it's clear now?

Comment: I have to see the lines of the second file in output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the python hint, I did it:

```
            file1 = open("FILE1.TXT", "r")
            a={}
            for line1 in file1:
                str = line1[:59] + line1[68:-1]
                a[str] = 1
            file1.close()

            file2 = open("FILE2.TXT", "r")
            out = open("OUTPUT.TXT", "w")
            for line2 in file2:
                str = line2[:59] + line2[68:-1]
                if not a.has_key(str):
                    out.write(line2[:-1])
            out.close()
            file2.close()
```

With two big files (2.8GB) it takes about 20 sec.

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

`diff` probably isn't the right tool for this, since you are only interested in comparing part of each line and only want output from the second file. You'll need to write your own comparison script, which is made easier because you are only interested in differences between corresponding lines in each file. An example in Python:

```
with open("FILE1.TXT", "r") as f1:
    with open("FILE2.TXT", "r") as f2:
        for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
            if (line1[:57] != line2[:57] or
                line1[68:] != line2[68:]):
                print line2
```

Comment: The result is incorrect, cause I have some new lines in the second file which are not contained in the first file. I'm updating the example rigth now